# UIAlertView backgroundImage

Tags: ios4

How can i set a background image in a UIAlertView progrmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no method to set the background image for AlertView. We need to set image as subView for alert View.

Try this way it will work:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"Message 1......\nMessage 2......" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

UIImageView *Image =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ImageName"]];
[alert addSubview:Image];

[Image release];

[alert show];
[alert release];
```

Comment: what about the Message 1....\n and Message 2....\n?What if i want to show message 1 and message 2 from 2 variable?

Comment: sorry i didn't understand what  you are saying? :(

Comment: noproblem..i made a way...i wanted to show each message in different line.just "\n" worked for me...thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

```
 UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"title" message:@"Empty data not Allowed" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil];



   UIImage *alertImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"custom-dialog-background.png"];

   UIImageView *backgroundImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:alertImage];

   backgroundImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 282, 130);

   backgroundImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;

   [alert addSubview:backgroundImageView];

   [alert sendSubviewToBack:backgroundImageView];


   [alert show];
```